# How to import to Azure DevOps CSV file with issues and epics (parent link) at single CSV file

Tags: azure-devops

I know how to do that at first importing epics, and fill CSV with issues in column parent link a new epics id's from azure. But when we got very big csv file from for example Jira with many relations to epic, how to do that in one Csv file, import Epics, Issues and on Issues set parent link to the new (old) Epics?

[Data schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXeGi.png)

```
Issue Type  Custom field (Epic Name)    Summary Custom field (Epic Link)    Description
```

Epic    Epic  1 Epic  1
Task        pfpfpf  SZKOL-45
Bug     important bug   SZKOL-45    important bug to solve
Bug     Test1   SZKOL-45

Comment: Could you add some screenshots to explain your query?

Comment: Is this link helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process?

Comment: Schema / data attached

Comment: Could you please elaborate what do you want to achieve? Maybe you can provide an example to explain it.

Comment: I'm just did it above. I want to export entire jira project (epics and task below epics) and import into azure devops. I don't see option to automatically during such of import into azure create epics and recreate connection between tasks and epics. So i suppose what i need to do: export from jira only epics. Import them in azure. After that export tasks with epic links, and in csv replace epic name to epic id from azure. and that import into azure.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to migrate work items from Jira to Azure DevOps. The main tool you can use to import work tracking data you've exported from elsewhere is Microsoft Excel. Excel supports publishing a flat list of work items or a hierarchical tree of parent-child linked work items. To learn more, see [Bulk add or modify work items with Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process).

Since you want to migrate from Jira to Azure DevOps, consider using the Marketplace extension, [Jira to Azure DevOps work item migration tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=solidify.jira-devops-migration). This tool provides support for the following tasks:

- Export Jira issues from Jira queries
- Map users from Jira to users in Azure DevOps
- Migrate work item field data
- Migrate links and attachments
- Migrate history

Answer (score 0):

it is impossible if you don't have access token in Jira